# sql: Delete in consideration two columns as tuples and check conditions with the elements(tuples) of list

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, db2

there is a table A like this

| employerId | employeeId | startDateA | endDateA | ** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 333 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-07 |  |
| 111 | 333 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-01-15 |  |
| 111 | 333 | 2022-01-17 | 2022-01-23 |  |

I need an sql delete statement for deleting all entries where **startDateA** > startDateB and **endDateA** < endDateB by giving startDateB and endDateB in a list as a pair like this (('2022-01-02', '2022-01-09'),('2022-01-10', '2022-01-16'),('2022-01-16', '2022-01-25').

I try to write an native query by giving as parameter this list:

```
List<Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
```

each element of the list is a pair. The left from pair is startDateB and the right of the pair is endDateB.

Can you help me to figure out the solution?

Comment: What is `startDateB`?  What is `endDateB` ?

Comment: You mention SQL statement so I assume you are not using JPA, right? Why tag it as Java then? It is not clear what you main about the Pair class in tuples

Comment: Can you [tag your DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) please.

Comment: the content of this list is to compare:      List<Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();   each element of the list is a pair. The left from pair is startDateB and the right of the pair is endDateB.

Comment: And what do you want to do with this list? Perform one delete for each pair? Perform one delete using all pairs ((where t.startDateA > :startDateB and endDateA < :endDateB) or (where t.startDateA > :startDateC and endDateA < :endDateC))

Comment: I want perform one delete using all pairs, for each pair with condition (where t.startDateA > :startDateB and endDateA < :endDateB), but by one delete statement.

Comment: I do not use jpa

Answer (score 0):

If you want such query to be used in Java you could do the following:

**Using Spring-data's JPARepository**

This solution assumes that you have a TableA class configured with JPA and that you are using Spring-data.

```
public interface TableARepository extends JPARepository<TableA> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from tableA t where t.startDateA > :startDateB and endDateA < :endDateB")
    int deleteByDates(@Param("startDateB") LocalDate startDateB, @Param("endDateB") LocalDate endDateB);
}
```

**Using EntityManager**

This solution assumes that you have JPA configured and a way to create an EntityManager for the transaction.

```
public int deleteByDates(LocalDate startDateB, LocalDate endDateB) {
    String sqlQuery = "delete from tableA t where t.startDateA > :startDateB and endDateA < :endDateB";
    EntityManager em = createEntityManager();
    try {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery);
        query.setParameter("startDateB", startDateB);
        query.setParameter("endDateB", endDateB);
        return query.executeUpdate();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

**Dealing with Pair**

In both cases you would call them with another method like this:

```
public int deleteByDates(Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate> pair) {
    return deleteByDates(pair.getValue0(), pair.getValue1());
}
```

**Dealing with List**

If you have a list of Pair then you could create the query in one method. There are several ways to do this, but simple and dirty it could be like this (a cleaner way would be using JPA Criteria https://thorben-janssen.com/criteria-updatedelete-easy-way-to/):

```
public int deleteByDates(List<Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>> datePairs) {
    if (datePairs == null || datePairs.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    String whereList = IntStream.range(0, datePairs.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> "(t.startDateA > :startDate" + i + " and endDateA < :endDate" + i + ")")
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" or "));
    String sqlQuery = "delete from tableA t where " + whereList;
    EntityManager em = createEntityManager();
    try {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery);
        IntStream.range(0, datePairs.size())
                .forEach(i -> {
                    query.setParameter("startDate" + i, datePairs[i].getValue0());
                    query.setParameter("endDate" + i, datePairs[i].getValue1());
                });
        return query.executeUpdate();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented this, this in one posible solution, but I should then loop each pair from this list:    List<Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>> pairs.  What I mean is, when i go through the loop for each pair and pass the pair as parameter in the deleteByDates(Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate> pair) as you prefer, then it would be success.  But what I need is a native query, where I can do it by one delete statement to handle all pairs without a loop.  You solution is exactly right, with going through the a loop.

Comment: I added a case to perform only one query using a List<Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>>. I am not proud of this very dirty and far from optimized solution, but it could help you get the idea of how to do this.